# Determine the dropbox folder and the google drive folder using c++ code?

Tags: c++, dropbox

I am writing a program for which I would like to automatically determine if dropbox is installed and if it is, save files in the dropbox folder to use as a synchronisation feature for the same program installed over a bunch of computers.

Comment: Okay, you are writing this program. What is your question precisely?

Comment: It looks like the dropbox interface is to interface directly with them via a REST interface.  IOW, you don't care whether they have it locally installed or not.  The user would need to enter their credentials into your app though.  There are a bunch of SDK's, but none for C++.  Check out: https://www.dropbox.com/developers